# convert seconds to timestamp in java

Tags: java, timestamp, unix-timestamp

How can I convert an int to timestamp ? for example 5 (seconds)?
I use this code to get the actual timestamp

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2007, 9 - 1, 23);
long millis = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

and want to add 5 seconds to the actual timestamp and compaire it to another one.

Answer (score 4):

Just do this...

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2007, 9 - 1, 23);
long millis = cal.getTimeInMillis();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
long millis5SecondsLater = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

[Look at this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: But it give me alwayse the same result 1190498405000 , maybe it's the years and date ?

Comment: Yes... the method [`getTimeInMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()) will return the number of milliseconds since the Epoch... This is what a timestamp is. Perhaps you should edit your question to reflect more precisely what it is you are trying to acheive